# Trying to block spam requests in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a numerous spam requests in nginx access/error logs like:

`/bcaashop/collections/new-era-new-era-indiana-pacers-nba-940-a-frame-snapback-black`

which I'm blocking in this way:

`if ($query_string ~ "\b(bca*.shop|nike|adidas)\b") {
  set $block_spam 1;
    }
if ($block_spam = 1) { 
  return 444;
}`

But if the request is ending in `.json` - for example:

`/bcaashop/collections/new-era-new-era-indiana-pacers-nba-940-a-frame-snapback-black.json`

it will give a 404 error in error.log, filling it with these similar requests errors.

I suspect this is because of following rule:

`location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|svg|woff|ttf|json|otf)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        expires 7d;
    }`

which contains json and overrides above rule. I've tried to change the rules order, but I still getting 404 instead of 444.

How to block the requests with json, properly? Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: Your `if` block tests the query string and not the URI, so I don't understand how the statements in your question are working. Are there other rules that are matching that particular URI? The `location` rules should not take precedence over the `If` block, unless the `if` block is itself nested within another `location`.

Comment: In this case the if statement is outside of mentioned location. The query_string as I know, contains the uri, and it blocks some spam requests